# Ethereum wallet does not allow transaction even after proper conditions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Ethereum Wallet shows "It seems this transaction will fail ......" even though I've used if/else inside contracts to ensure that transfer value does not go higher than contract balance.`

```
  function mySales( address a) constant public canWithdraw returns (uint){
    return totalSales[a];
}

function topSalesPerson() constant public returns ( address ){
    return topsales;
}

event bonusDepleted(string);

function submitSales() public payable canWithdraw{

    uint amount = msg.value;
    uint bonus_temp;
    if (this.balance >0){
        if(amount > 50000000000000000000){
            bonus_temp = amount/10; // 10% bonus
        }
        if(bonus_temp > 20000000000000000000){
            bonus_temp = 20000000000000000000;  // max bonus = 20 ether
        }

        if (this.balance > bonus_temp){
             msg.sender.transfer(bonus_temp);  // transfer bonus in case of enough balance
        }
       else{
            msg.sender.transfer(this.balance); // else transfer remaining amount as Bonus 
       }
        owner.transfer(amount);

        Bonus[msg.sender] += bonus_temp;
        totalSales[msg.sender] += msg.value;

        if( totalSales[topsales] < totalSales[msg.sender]){
            topsales = msg.sender;
        }
    }

    if(this.balance == 0){
        bonusDepleted("Bonus has reached its limit and no bonus will be provided for future sales");
    }
}`
```

So if contract has 3 ethers then for 50 ether it allows txn but for 60 it shows warning and error "intrinsic gas too low" where as it should have just refunded last 3 ether.

Also for Readonly functions like "mySales", how to invoke them from "ethereum -wallet"  as it does not return anything on entering address into this function under "Read from Contract Section". i'm able to use it from command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
if (this.balance > bonus_temp){
    msg.sender.transfer(bonus_temp);  // transfer bonus in case of enough balance
}
else {
    msg.sender.transfer(this.balance); // else transfer remaining amount as Bonus 
}
owner.transfer(amount);
```

There's no guarantee that there are sufficient funds for the `transfer` to the `owner`. In particular, any time `amount` is positive and you process the `else` clause, the contract's balance will then be zero, and the line after it will revert the transaction.

A reasonable fix might be to do the `transfer` to `owner` *before* you calculate the bonus, but it really depends on the behavior you want.